# Snippet of code does not process MS Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro with 1,300+ lines of VBA that does many things within a spreadsheet. The last few commands are copied below.

The "Compare City" section always works, the "Compare ADDRESS" section always works. The "Compare STATE" never works.

"Compare STATE" only works if I run it in a separate macro. (By itself) Or, it runs if I move it to a different section (at the beginning of the code, or in the middle of the code, etc) but it only works the first time I run it. If I open a new file, City, Address, Zip work (They do exactly the same thing as "STATE" but on different columns.) but the STATE logic does not work.

I do not get error messages. It simply does not copy Not Null to the Null cell.

' Compare STATE on left and right. If both empty or full, no action. If one empty other full, copy to empty.

```
For x = 2 To RowsInFile
    
    LeftCell = "G" & x
    RightCell = "FN" & x

    
        If IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = True And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = False Then
                Range(RightCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = False And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = True Then
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(RightCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
Next x
```

' Compare CITY on left and right. If both empty or full, no action. If one empty other full, copy to empty.

```
For x = 2 To RowsInFile
    
    LeftCell = "F" & x
    RightCell = "FM" & x


        If IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = True And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = False Then
                Range(RightCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = False And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = True Then
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(RightCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
Next x
```

' Compare ADDRESS on left and right. If both empty or full, no action. If one empty other full, copy to empty.

```
For x = 2 To RowsInFile
    
    LeftCell = "D" & x
    RightCell = "FL" & x

    
        If IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = True And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = False Then
                Range(RightCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range(LeftCell)) = False And IsEmpty(Range(RightCell)) = True Then
                Range(LeftCell).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Range(RightCell).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
Next x
```

Comment: You can probably get rid of at least half of the lines in your code if the rest resembles what you have shared here. `.Select` is not necessary. `CutCopyMode = False` is not necessary (You can use it once right at the end). You are using a strange way to loop through cells. Room for improvement is strong with this one :)

Comment: `IsEmpty` may not be doing what you think here - it tests the `Variant` type to determine if it is `VT_EMPTY`. It will return false for an empty string or if there is a formula in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to loop through the same values of `x` multiple times. Just nest everything inside the same loop.
2. Qualify every instance of `Range` with a worksheet. `With`/`End With` block will do some justice here
3. You do not need to `Select` a cell to move, modify, or delete it. This means you also do not need to rely on `Active` or `Selection`. All instance of them have been removed here
4. You can set values equal to each other which will speed things up (the larger the value of `RowsInFile`, the more the benefit you will see)
5. You can make this moderately easier to follow by just testing if the range is blank with `vbNullString` or `""` like so (`If Range(?) = vbNullString Then` or `If Range(?) = "" Then`
6. `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is just taking up space here. You can remove all instances of this from your code and leave this line once right before `End Sub`

---

```
For x = 2 To RowsInFile

    If IsEmpty(Range("G" & x)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("FN" & x)) = False Then
        Range("G" & x).Value = Range("FN" & x).Value
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("G" & x)) = False And IsEmpty(Range("FN" & x)) = True Then
        Range("FN" & x).Value = Range("G" & x).Value
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Range("F" & x)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("FM" & x)) = False Then
        Range("F" & x).Value = Range("FM" & x).Value
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("F" & x)) = False And IsEmpty(Range("FM" & x)) = True Then
        Range("FM" & x).Value = Range("F" & x).Value
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Range("D" & x)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("FL" & x)) = False Then
        Range("FL" & x).Value = Range("D" & x).Value
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("D" & x)) = False And IsEmpty(Range("FL" & x)) = True Then
        Range("FL" & x).Value = Range("D" & x).Value
    End If

Next x
```

---

7. Welcome to **Stack Overflow**. Thanks for sharing code on your first post! You're off to a great start

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to vba coding and am learning as I go along. The code you provided works great. I've taken everyo0ne's comments to heart and will use the lessons to improve my work. FYI most of the lines of my code are for adding column labels and formatting. I would say 25% of the lines are custom code. I'll use what you all have shared and improve where possible. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I spoke too soon. The same problem has returned. More detail: Users are supposed to enter address, city, state and zip in columns on the left side of the sheet. (they enter text, not formulas) They are supposed to enter the same into columns on the far right of the spreadsheet. Some people enter in on the left side columns and forget the right side columns. Some enter it on the right and forget the left. They code should look to see if they entered it on one side and copy to the other. If both sides are empty or both side have something, the code does not need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's not too much information but try something like this.

If copying formatting isn't important:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim LeftCellColumn As Integer
Dim RightCellColumn As Integer

LeftCellColumn = Range("G" & 1).Column
RightCellColumn = Range("FN" & 1).Column

For x = 2 To RowsInFile
    With ActiveSheet
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn)) = True And IsEmpty(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn)) = False Then

                .Cells(x, LeftCellColumn).Value = .Cells(x, RightCellColumn).Value

        ElseIf IsEmpty(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn)) = False And IsEmpty(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn)) = True Then

                 .Cells(x, RightCellColumn).Value = .Cells(x, LeftCellColumn).Value
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

Alternatively this if you want that formatting:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim LeftCellColumn As Integer
Dim RightCellColumn As Integer

LeftCellColumn = Range("G" & 1).Column
RightCellColumn = Range("FN" & 1).Column

For x = 2 To RowsInFile
    With ActiveSheet
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn)) = True And IsEmpty(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn)) = False Then

                .Range(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn), .Cells(x, RightCellColumn)).Copy .Range(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn), .Cells(x, LeftCellColumn))

        ElseIf IsEmpty(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn)) = False And IsEmpty(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn)) = True Then

                .Range(.Cells(x, LeftCellColumn), .Cells(x, LeftCellColumn)).Copy .Range(.Cells(x, RightCellColumn), .Cells(x, RightCellColumn))
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, providing us with some data you put into this formulas would help.

By the way, in the first code that 'With ActiveSheet' wasn't neccessary, in the second it didn't want to run without this. You can change that 'ActiveSheet' for 'WorkSheets(1)' or 'WorkSheets("Name").

Comment: Thank you. I have learned how to code by using stackoverflow. True to form, you all are very helpful and I will learn from your suggestions and examples.